# Using HTML ASCII

Tags: html

Rookie question. 
Would guys recommend using Html ASCII or does the browser handle this part? I was reading through W3Schools and I’m just curious if this is something I should always consider as a good habit.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you give a code example?

Comment: Hi Jon B, 

So I was just curious if it is good practice to use Unicode characters. I was going through W3schools, and I wanted to know if this is something I should always keep in mind writing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to include `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` of your HTML documents. This lets the browser know that your document is encoded with Unicode.

It's perfectly fine to use Unicode characters in an HTML document, but it's better to use HTML entity names or entity numbers.
(see a list of entity names and numbers and learn more on
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_symbols.asp).)

According to w3schools,

> If you use an HTML entity name or a hexadecimal number,
>   the character will always display correctly.
>   This is independent of what character set (encoding) your page uses!

This means that entity names and numbers are guaranteed to work, even if you don't put `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Thank you so much, Skylar. That's very helpful.

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer, please accept it.